# Web API 2 serializer selection

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api2

In web api 2 controller handling request with "Accept: application/xml" header field.

```
public class ConverterController : ApiController
{
    class A {}
    public class B {}
    public class C : Exception {}

    public IHttpActionResult Action()
    {
       var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, new A());
       // res.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json"

       var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, new B());
       // res.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/xml"

       var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, new C());
       // res.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json"
    }
}
```

Why class A and C is serializing to json?

Comment: Response format depend on the request `Accept` header

Comment: It is Accept: application/xml

Comment: Not exactly, `Accept` header is for content negotiation which means that the server will return a response with the requested MIME type only if it is available, otherwise it will return its default.

Comment: @Jonas, If you want to force them to return XML format you can use an overload of the CreateResponse extension method `var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new B(), Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);`.

Comment: If forced it throws {"The configured formatter 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter' cannot write an object of type 'C'."}

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when there is an exception in XML serializer web api 2 silently falls back to JSON serializer. Thanks to AarónBC for the hint that must force XML serializer to get serialization exception.

```
var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new C(), Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```